# Cannot connect to https://api.elephantsql.com from pg admin

Tags: postgresql

has anyone success to create connection to elephantsql.org using pgadmin?

i want to try to store my database on a server and im trying to use elephantsqlcom

i want to connect to it using pg admin to make maintenance easier. i have followed this instruction : https://www.elephantsql.com/docs/pgadmin.html but keep getting this error

[image]
what should i do? thanks all

Answer (score 3):

change database name from `postgres` to `xwpgagbb` similar to:

[image]

see user **AND DEFAULT DATABASE** are the same?..