# Not able to connect pgAdmin4 with elephantsql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to use elephantsql with pgadmin but not able to connect.
Below is the my issue:-"

**FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "169.149.233.33", user "tfndkxmm", database "aaehpcif", SSL on 

FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "169.149.233.33", user "tfndkxmm", database "aaehpcif", SSL off**

i am following this instruction : https://www.elephantsql.com/docs/pgadmin.html but keep getting this error.
I had seen similar question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747190/cannot-connect-to-https-api-elephantsql-com-from-pg-admin).But it doesn't solve my problem.
I am also attaching my connection [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlZwi.png) here.
Please someone help me to resolve this issue. 
**Thanks**

Comment: What is in the `pg_hba.conf` file in the server?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe as i connect with elephantsql server 4851 databases appear.I have not created any of the database. When i click on any of the database this error appears which i have mentioned above.

Comment: Then you should ask the database administrator to give you access.